# How to create a button with another button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create an Android app that you can build a task list in. When you click the "Add New Task" button, it creates a button with a checkbox below. Then if you click it again, it creates another below the previously created one.

The newly created buttons take you to an activity that allows you to enter in your task title, due date for the task and description of the task.

I am new to Android Studio and have only ever used Visual Studio, which is not as complicated as this program.

I know how to create a button with another button using JFrames/JButtons in Java, but not in Android Studio.

I also am not sure how to set it to where each newly created button has its own activity created.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you need to have a new task fragment that you add to your activity in a scrollview layout. Allowing you to manage each task in its own context. Allowing you start a new intent for your activity you want to launch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ListView` where you can have a custom row view of your checkbox. 
This can be achieved by using a simple List to populate the `ListView`. Add an item to the list when you click the "Add new Task" button and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Possible code :

**Data.class** (A class model for title, due date, description)

```
public class Data {

    String title, dueDate, description;

    public void setTitle(String title){
       this.title = title;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc){
       this.description = description;
    }
    public void setDue(String due){
       this.dueDate = due;
    }
    public void getTitle(){
       return title;
    }
    public void getDesc(){
       return description;
    }
    public void getDue(){
       return dueDate;
    }
}
```

In your activity create,

`List<Data> items = new ArrayList<>();`

Say, your `ListView` `Adapter` instance is called `taskAdapter`,
Use the `items` as your data set in the `Adapter`.
Inflate your custom view with `CheckBox` on `getView()`.

And, say your button instance is called `addTaskButton` and in the `onClick()` of the same do this.

```
Data data = new Data();
items.add(data);
taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And, define a `onListItemClicked` listener where you'll have the index of the `items`. Pass the index to the New `Activity` to collect data and use `onActivityResult()` to update the data for the index.

Comment: Doesn't he have to save those buttons for future use to SharedPreferences or a database?

Comment: He can very well save the list of items in his database and use a Cursor to load them up again in the List.